# SQL Query for filling a SINGLE column with values

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have an existing SQL database table I'm interacting with over pyodbc. I have written a class that uses pyodbc to interact with the database by performing reads and creating and deleting columns. The final bit of functionality I require is the ability to fill a created column (full of NULLs by default) with values from a python list (that I plan to iterate over and then finalize with db.commit()) - without having an effect on other columns or adding extra rows.

I tried the following query iterated over in a for loop;

```
 INSERT INTO table_name (required_column) VALUES (value)
```

Thus the class method;

```
    def writeToColumn(self, columnName, tableName, writeData):
    for item in writeData:
        self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ' + tableName + '(' + columnName + ') VALUES (' + item + ')')

    self.cursor.commit()
```

Where value represent the current index value of a list.

But this adds an entire new row and fills cells of columns of not mentioned with nulls.

what I want to do is replace all of the data in a column without the other columns being effected in any way. Is there some query that can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: So basically you're looking for an update? The syntax is available all over the net. Or in Daniel's response below.

Answer (score 4):

Not surprisingly, calling INSERT will always insert a new row, hence the name. If you need to update an existing row, you need to call UPDATE.

```
UPDATE table_name SET required_column=value WHERE ...
```

where the WHERE condition identifies your existing row somehow (probably via the primary key).

Comment: what if I were to have no where statement, would it just fill form the lowest index?